# Use .htaccess to make all PDF files, regardless of folder, appear to be in a folder called /pdf/

Tags: .htaccess, pdf

I currently have PDFs in a number of different folders and sub folders.

I'm looking for a way to use .htaccess to make any pdf URL appear as if they are in the same folder eg.

This: https://example.com/random/random/filename.pdf

To this: https://example.com/pdf/filename.pdf

So far I have tried

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ([^\/]+\.pdf)$ /pdf/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

which doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks.

EDIT - To clarify, I'm looking to redirect a file url to a file of the same name but without knowing the destination folder it is in, which I realise may not be possible.

Comment: Making this an external redirect would not make too much sense, if you wanted to _hide_ where the PDF is actually located. But other than that, I don't see anything wrong. If there is more to your rewrite setup, then please shows these lines in context.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^\/]+\.pdf)$ random/random/$1 [NC]
```

it worked for me.
Restart your web server after making these changes to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure why you have random/random in your answer? This was in the example only to denote that the pdf files may be in a range of folders that are unknown. Your example looks like you are trying to write /pdf/example.pdf to  random/random/example.pdf which is not what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: My example turns the url https://example.com/random/random/filename.pdf into https://example.com/pdf/filename.pdf, as you said in your question.

Comment: You need to replace the random/random/ path with the actual path that stores your pdf files

Comment: Thanks but that path is unknown, they are in many different folders. I need a catch-all for a PDF in any location.